# Automatically open the Safari Debugger when the iPhone Simulator is launched

Tags: iphone, xcode, safari, automator

The iOS web debugger in Safari is the bee's knees, but it closes every time the Simulator is restarted. Not only is it annoying to re-open it from the menu after every build, but it makes it tricky to debug any behavior that happens during startup.

Is there a way to set up a trigger in Xcode to automatically open the Safari debugger after every build, or perhaps a way to build a shell script or Automator action to do a build and immediately open the debugger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a partial solution.  This opens the debug window of Safari with one click which is a lot better but not automatic.

Open `Script Editor` on your mac (Command + Space Bar and type in Script Editor)

Paste in this code:

```
-- `menu_click`, by Jacob Rus, September 2006
-- 
-- Accepts a list of form: `{"Finder", "View", "Arrange By", "Date"}`
-- Execute the specified menu item.  In this case, assuming the Finder 
-- is the active application, arranging the frontmost folder by date.

on menu_click(mList)
    local appName, topMenu, r

    -- Validate our input
    if mList's length < 3 then error "Menu list is not long enough"

    -- Set these variables for clarity and brevity later on
    set {appName, topMenu} to (items 1 through 2 of mList)
    set r to (items 3 through (mList's length) of mList)

    -- This overly-long line calls the menu_recurse function with
    -- two arguments: r, and a reference to the top-level menu
    tell application "System Events" to my menu_click_recurse(r, ((process appName)'s ¬
        (menu bar 1)'s (menu bar item topMenu)'s (menu topMenu)))
end menu_click

on menu_click_recurse(mList, parentObject)
    local f, r

    -- `f` = first item, `r` = rest of items
    set f to item 1 of mList
    if mList's length > 1 then set r to (items 2 through (mList's length) of mList)

    -- either actually click the menu item, or recurse again
    tell application "System Events"
        if mList's length is 1 then
            click parentObject's menu item f
        else
            my menu_click_recurse(r, (parentObject's (menu item f)'s (menu f)))
        end if
    end tell
end menu_click_recurse

menu_click({"Safari", "Develop", "Simulator", "index.html"})
```

Once the simulator has opened, click run on your script (you might need to allow the script editor in the settings the first time).

(Optional)  You can save your the scripts as an app so that you don't have to have the script editor open.

Comment: This answer is slightly out of date.  Replace "IOS Simulator" with "Simulator"

Comment: @TomKrones That's great, unfortunately it doesn't work on OSX 10.12 Could you update this script for the current version of applescript?

Comment: I have improved the @TomKrones code so that you don't have to specify the `index.html` entry. My suggestion is to save the script as an Application, put it in the Dock and just click it when you need it. Gist: https://gist.github.com/toioski/44abee301719d090808727d46c0567bc

Answer (score 4):

There is [question that should be marked a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073496/when-ios-simulator-starts-is-it-possible-to-automatically-load-the-web-inspecto) that describes using setTimeout() to give you enough time to switch windows over to Safari and set a breakpoint.

Something like this, where startMyApp is the bootstrap function of your app:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  startMyApp();
}, 20000);
```

It is super ghetto, but does work. I've submitted a feature request via http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html too to close the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Extending upon the @Prisoner's answer, if you use WKWebView you could:

```
    let contentController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()


    let pauseForDebugScript = WKUserScript(source: "window.alert(\"Go, turn on Inspector, I'll hold them back!\")",
                                           injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart,
                                           forMainFrameOnly: true)
    contentController.addUserScript(pauseForDebugScript)

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController
    //Init browser with configuration (our injected script)
    browser = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: view.frame.width, height: containerView.frame.height), configuration:config)
```

also important thing is to implement alert handler from `WKUIDelegate` protocol

```
//MARK: WKUIDelegate
func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message, message: nil,
                                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        _ in completionHandler()}
    );

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {});
}
```

and one little thing just in case you could have an `UIAlertController:supportedInterfaceOrientations was invoked recursively` error add following extension ([From this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010520/923340))

```
extension UIAlertController {     
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining Tom's answer with my solution, first do the following:

- Create an application as Tom describes above
- In "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility" add your new Script Applicaiton and make sure it is allowed to control your computer

Now, I'm using cordova and from the command line the following builds, runs emulator and opens safari debug console:

```
cordova build ios; cordova emulate ios; open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app; sleep 1 ; open /PATH/TO/OpenDevelop.app/
```

Make sure to replace /PATH/TO/ with the appropriate path to where you saved your script.

Answer (score -4):

Humm,I don't think you can do that,but you can just "CTRL+R" in the web debugger.

Comment: I'm removing your self-promotional link, which does not answer the question. Please do not include links in this manner in the future.

Comment: Did you read the post yet?Is not a way to help him?Sometimes some link it's not an AD!

Comment: You have been posting that link over and over and over again. That's the very definition of spam. Stop doing that.

Comment: Please just remove the answer if it does not help!

Comment: This only half-works in my case; the UIWebView reloads, but PhoneGap plugins are not re-initialized, leading to errors until the app is relaunched.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Safari debug window is closed when the app is stopped.